# How to properly rotating a material using node which has a normal map?

Tags: materials, uv, node-editor, normal-map

Rotating normal map via mapping node seems will flip normal map, resulting a weird looking material. But directly rotating uv map in uv editor doesn't cause any issue.
So how to properly rotating a material using node which has a normal map?
Thanks in advance!
[image: 0 degree rotation]

[image: 180 degree rotation]

Edit: .blend file added 
[Here is the blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52674)

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. What did you plug into the Mapping Node's Vector input?

Comment: Thanks for reply, it's UV socket of texture coordinate node.